# codeigniter suppress disable on a single view

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to turn off the errors on a single view in codeigniter.

Right now I am still developing, and my default landing page is something of a splash screen of sorts, so while Im developing I randomly break my script all the way down the run and it shows up on any view. With that I need to turn it off just on that one view, since the rest of the site is behind that and theres no links or references otherwise leading anywhere into the build currently.

I don't want to turn off all errors for obvious reasons. But i need them off on that one page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller or view for which you want to disable error display, do

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

After invoking the view, you can do:

```
ini_restore('display_errors');
```

to make errors appear again (assuming your default setting is to display errors).

More details:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Comment: Or you could be like a *sane* person and use `error_reporting()`.  http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I ended up putting the error_reporting in just the one controller.. works fine at suppressing what and where I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

„If you would like to dynamically set a config item or change an existing one, you can do so using”:

```
$this->config->set_item('item_name', 'item_value');
```

In your case:

```
$this->config->set_item('log_threshold', 0);
```

You can use this function in your Controller or, also in View.